# How to send a String read from and IO to a user defined function

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to make an infinite loop where I send the user's input to a parsing function which reads the contents of the string when they enter a valid string

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
            putStrLn ("\n" ++ "This is blah :" ++ "\n" ++ "=================================")
            putStrLn ("Valid Inputs" ++ "\n" ++ "=================================")
            loop 

--Infinite Loop
---------------------           
loop :: IO()
loop = do 
            input <- getLine
            if input == ""
                then return()
                else do 
                    parse input
                    print input
                    loop



--Main Parsing Function (Does't work)
--------------------
--parse:: String -> String 
--parse (x:xs) = if x == 'a' then 'b':parse xs
               --else x:parse xs
```

My question is how can I send user input to my parsing function. I have received errors

Saying inferring type `IO t` 
in `parse :: String -> String`
I Change it to:

```
parse:: IO String -> String
```

then gives me another error saying
inferred `type [a]` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

> parse input

returns a String, but it should return `IO` "something", because you are in a `do`-block. So you could instead write

```
 print (parse input)
```

Your `parse` function is not complete, you must add a pattern-case for `[]`

If you wanted to change your type of `parse`, then it had to be `String -> IO String`.
But that is not a good programming style, because where no impurity is needed, no impurity should be :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help i changed print input to print (parse input) and
parse:: String -> String to parse:: String -> [Char] and it worked

Comment: String -> String was okay, because [Char] = String